# Not able to login to cqlsh in Cassandra cluster of 3 nodes hosted in Google cloud platform

Tags: cassandra

I'm setting up a 3 node Cassandra cluster and after installing
    cassandra I tried to connect to cassandra using 'cqlsh'

```
I'm not able to connect to cassandra db terminal. 
rammady@deb-cassandra-ram-1:~$ cqlsh 10.142.0.76 Connection error:
('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried
connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection
refused")})

I've modified cassandra.yaml file and provided 1: private ip address
under seed    -seed:10.142.0.75,10.142.0.76,10.142.0.77 2:
listen_address: 10.142.0.75  3: rpc_address: 10.142.0.75
```

Comment: is the cluster alive? what does `nodetool status` return?

Comment: Hi @CarlosMonroyNieblas thanks for your reply ..............................................sudo nodetool status
nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to the ip you defined in the config:

```
cqlsh 10.142.0.75
```

netstat -tulpn would show you, that the node is listening not on the loopback if.

Comment: Hi Alex thanks for your reply but even "cqlsh 10.142.0.75" is also not working .

Comment: Please connect to the host, and run: netstat -tulpn and nodetool status

Comment: Hi Alex Thanks again ....my system log error is as below===============================================================

Comment: ERROR [main] 2019-04-12 09:37:41,748 CassandraDaemon.java:749 - Cannot start node if snitch's rack (d) differs from previous rack (b). Please fix the snitch configuration, decommission and rebootstrap this node or use the flag -Dcassandra.ignore_rack=true.

Comment: obviously you changed the rack name, as the error states. if you are starting a fresh cluster then you could try deleting the data folder or change the rack name back to "b"

Comment: Values are missing in netstat -tulpn and nodetool statust

Comment: tcp        0      0 10.142.0.84:9042        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   </br>tcp        0      0 10.142.0.84:7000        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   <br/>tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7199          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -

Comment: your node is listening on  10.142.0.84:9042. cqlsh 10.142.0.84 should work.

Comment: 10.142.0.84:9042 value from "netstat -tulpn and nodetool status" is from another GCP vm ,here I deployed cassandra manually but the GCP VM where I deployed cassandra using ansible playbook is not showing value 10.142.0.84:9042.Hence I asked here.